# Why Android Studio is showing error : Unable to start adb server: error: could not install *smartsocket* listener

Tags: android

I am getting this unexpected behaviour of Android studio.It is showing me this error 
'Unable to create Debug Bridge: Unable to start adb server: error: could not install *smartsocket* listener:'
Android studio was working fine before updating (it was 1.5), as soon as I updated to Android studio 2.0 I started facing this issue.[image: This is error screen comes when i start android studio]

I checked in task manager and could not find this port(5037) being used.What is the actual cause of it I could not figure this thing out.Any help?

Answer (score 8):

Are you using Genymotion?

If **yes** than my solution might help you. The issue is that genymotion uses its own adb server instead of Android SDK adb server (with the same port number, which is a conflict obviously). To fix this go to **Genymotion** -> **Settings** -> **ADB** and choose **Use custom Android SDK Tools**. Possible restart is needed.

[image: genymotions]

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

In my case Just Restart or Turn OFF or ON it will work fine..

In some cases if u use Genymotion then it conflict with the Android Studio ADB 
Just Kill it and start ADB from PlateForm Tools Inside SDK